# Errors running sail build

Tags: docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail

Running sail build I get the following errors:

```
#7 91.31 Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.hfO5Uiq59J/gpg.1.sh --homedir /root/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C
#7 92.16 gpg: key 00A6F0A3C300EE8C: public key "Launchpad Stable" imported
#7 92.16 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#7 92.16 gpg:               imported: 1
#7 93.06 Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute InRelease [23.9 kB]
#7 93.07 Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [110 kB]
#7 93.10 Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
#7 93.16 Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
#7 93.16   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 93.23 Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
#7 93.23   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 93.44 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [115 kB]
#7 93.65 Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
#7 93.65   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 94.06 Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
#7 94.06   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 94.47 Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [101 kB]
#7 94.84 Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
#7 94.84   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 94.85 Reading package lists...
#7 95.60 W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 95.60 E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' is not signed.
#7 95.60 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 95.60 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 95.60 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
#7 95.60 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev        php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd        php8.1-curl        php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring        php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap        php8.1-intl php8.1-readline        php8.1-ldap        php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole        php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 100
```

If the errors were on a normal Ubunut machine I could probably run commands to add keyfiles and certificates, but running inside Docker, I don't know what I can do.

I have tried updating Docker and `composer update`.

I am running Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never-mind... it was just running out of disk space. I allocated more resources and it ran fine.
I just wish it would give a space warning instead of something else...